# nginx workers stack at 100% usage after X random days

Tags: nginx, cpu-usage, troubleshooting

I am facing a strange incident, under which my two nginx workers suddenly get stack at 100% of CPU usage after a random number of days and at the same web traffic, under which they are behaving fine during the other days.

It serves a light traffic of 5concurrent requests per second and my nginx worker's config is set as follow:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_cpu_affinity auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

pcre_jit on;

events
{
        multi_accept on;
        worker_connections 2048;
        accept_mutex on;
        use epoll;
}
```

No matter if I change the processes to auto or to a static amount (i've tried 1), i get a 100% starting after ~6 days. Here is a screenshot of my current htop: [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/nkb7hp)

If i restart my nginx service, load will return to normal. After 5-6 days, it will hit 100% again.

I've tried usign tools like ngxtop, but I am not able to identify the real cause of the load, but only to verify that this is not happening from a website source.

I've also restarted php7.3-fpm and nginx's CPU usage is still 100%, which means to mean that something else is going wrong.

Im not aware of any debugging tools for such a case and I would be thankful in advance if you can guide me on the proper tools in order to debug it.

Helpful information:

I am using [WordOps](https://wordops.net/) ready-made stack script.
Nginx is on version 1.14.2

Comment: What operating system, Linux?

Comment: `strace`.  Or `gdb` if you're feeling adventurous.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, it is easy to profile exactly what code is on CPU.

Install debug symbols of the kernel and your app (nginx) so you have human readable function names.

Run `perf top` to see the top symbols on CPU. [perf_events reference](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html)

Generate a [flame graph visualization](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html#perf) using perf or bcc.

[Review basic utilization with a handful of useful tools](http://www.brendangregg.com/Articles/Netflix_Linux_Perf_Analysis_60s.pdf). Or look at [netdata](https://my-netdata.io/) for the same thing.

```
uptime
dmesg | tail
vmstat 1
mpstat -P ALL 1
pidstat 1
iostat -xz 1
free -m
sar -n DEV 1
sar -n TCP,ETCP 1
top
```

Then the difficult part: determine what causes it. Could be app code (PHP?) could be web server (nginx) could be OS tuning (Linux).  Get familiar with the entire stack and what it is doing.